In the java code below which is a method of a larger program my ArrayList is returning empty but the objects being added can be printed
public static ArrayList<Vehicle> loadVehicles(String filePath) {

    ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {

        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.startsWith("[Vehicle]")) {

                String makeModel = null;
                String quality = null;
                int seats = 0;
                int rentalPrice = 0;
                boolean available = false;
                
                // Read each attribute of the vehicle
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                    String[] parts = line.split(": ");
                    switch (parts[0]) {

                        case "MakeModel":
                            makeModel = parts[1];
                            break;

                        case "Quality":
                            quality = parts[1];
                            break;

                        case "Seats":
                            seats = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                            break;

                        case "RentalPrice":
                            rentalPrice = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
                            break;

                        case "Available":
                            available = Boolean.parseBoolean(parts[1]);
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
                
                // Create and add the vehicle to the list
                Vehicle v = new Vehicle(makeModel, quality, seats, 
                                    rentalPrice, available);
                vehicles.add(v);
                System.out.println(vehicles);
                System.out.println(v);

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return vehicles;
}

I tried printing out the ArrayList and nothing is printed I checked the size and its 0
I have ensure that the file is indeed being read and data retrieved but I dont understand why the arrayList size is 0

It is a perfect opportunity for you to learn debugging and logging. To start I would recommend printing something unique inside each case statement.

You haven't shown the Vehicle class but in general, if you want sensible output you'll need to override the toString() method in the Vehicle class. Still, you should see evidence of a growing vehicles list as your loop progresses. For a complete [mre] you should show your Vehicle class and a short file that illustrates the problem.

Show the code that calls your loadVehicles method and how it determines the list is empty.

Also, since empty lines in the input file are used to separate vehicles, you might want to trim out all whitespace before testing for emptyness, i.e. change line.isEmpty() to line.trim().isEmpty().

are you saying that System.out.println(v); is indeed printing the vehicle, but System.out.println(vehicles); is printing an empty list even after vehicles.add(v);  in posted code ?!?
